# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes <swiper-slide> vite+ ts

Tags: typescript, swiper.js, vite

I have been testing the following example https://codesandbox.io/s/w9vd2, about vite + ts and the example has worked without problem, the problem occurs when generating the production package with the command:

npm run build

Vite is giving me the following error.

src / App.vue: 4: 4 - TS2322 error: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Partial <{zoom: boolean; tag: string; virtualIndex: string | number; }> & Omit <Readonly <{tag: {type: StringConstructor; default: string; }; swiperRef: {...; }; zoom: {...; }; virtualIndex: {...; }; }> & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps, DefaultKeys <... >> '.
Property 'swiperRef' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Omit <Readonly <{tag: {type: StringConstructor; default: string; }; swiperRef: {type: Swiper; required: false; }; zoom: {type: BooleanConstructor; default: undefined; }; virtualIndex: {...; }; }> & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps, DefaultKeys <... >> '.

4  Slide 1   Slide 2   Slide 3   Slide 4 </ swiper -slide>  Slide 5   Slide 6   Slide 7   Slide 8 < / swiper-slide>  Slide 9

the code I am testing is the following:

```
<template>
<swiper :navigation="true" class="mySwiper">
  <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 4</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 5</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 6</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 7</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 8</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 9</swiper-slide>
  </swiper>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
// Import Swiper Vue.js components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';

// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/css';

import "swiper/css/navigation"

import './style.css';


// import Swiper core and required modules
import SwiperCore, {
  Navigation
} from 'swiper';

// install Swiper modules
SwiperCore.use([Navigation]);


export default {
  components: {
    Swiper,
    SwiperSlide,
  },
  setup() {
    return {
        
        
    };
  },
  methods: {
    
  }
  
}
</script>
```

My tsconfig.json is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    //se egregaron estos 2 para solventar problemas de compilacion de produccion
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowJs": true,
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"]
}
```

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

solution:

update swiper 7.0.9

npm i swiper@7.0.9